# JAVAFX two stages beside bug

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to display two `Stage`s perfectly beside each other without space between them but I have this:

[image: screen capture]

I tried some alternatives but got the same problem. It seems that the second stage don't fill all the space provided. Any ideas?

```java
public class Main extends Application {
    static final double STEP=10;
    static final double X_DIM=500;
    static final double Y_DIM=300;
    static final double SPACING=10;
    static final double RADIUS=50;
    static final Color FILL1= Color.BLUE;
    static final Color FILL2= Color.GREEN;
    static final Color FILL3= Color.RED;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primarystage) throws Exception {
        Button moveCircle= new Button("Move Circle 1");
        Button addCircle= new Button("Add Circle 2");
        Button reset= new Button("Reset");
        Button exit= new Button("exit");
        reset.setDisable(true);

        Circle circle1= new Circle(X_DIM/2,Y_DIM/2,RADIUS,FILL1);
       
        StackPane root = new StackPane(circle1);
        VBox buttons= new VBox(moveCircle,addCircle,reset,exit);
        buttons.setPadding(new Insets(SPACING,SPACING,SPACING,SPACING));
        buttons.setSpacing(SPACING);
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        primarystage.setTitle("LAB4");
        primarystage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 300));
        primarystage.show();

        Stage stage2= new Stage();
        stage2.setTitle("stage2");
        stage2.setX(primarystage.getX()+primarystage.getWidth());
        stage2.setY(primarystage.getY());
        stage2.setScene(new Scene(buttons));
        stage2.show();
        stage2.setMinWidth(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the better solution here would be to use a single stage with a BorderPane or SplitPane.

Comment: Also consider a modeless `Dialog`.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue on a Mac (OS X 12.3.1, JavaFX 18.0.1).  When I run your application, the stages are flush against each other with no gap.

Answer (score 4):

Refer to the documentation for [widthProperty](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html#widthProperty)
(Paraphrased excerpts.)

> The width of this Window. This value includes any and all decorations which may be added by the Operating System such as resizable frame handles.

When you want to widen the stage by dragging its border with the mouse, the mouse pointer changes to a double-headed arrow which extends beyond the border and that is why you have a gap between the borders of the two `Stage`s. Try using the `Scene` width, rather than the `Stage` width.

Consider the following code:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    static final double STEP=10;
    static final double X_DIM=500;
    static final double Y_DIM=300;
    static final double SPACING=10;
    static final double RADIUS=50;
    static final Color FILL1= Color.BLUE;
    static final Color FILL2= Color.GREEN;
    static final Color FILL3= Color.RED;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primarystage) throws Exception {
        Button moveCircle= new Button("Move Circle 1");
        Button addCircle= new Button("Add Circle 2");
        Button reset= new Button("Reset");
        Button exit= new Button("exit");
        reset.setDisable(true);

        Circle circle1= new Circle(X_DIM/2,Y_DIM/2,RADIUS,FILL1);
       
        StackPane root = new StackPane(circle1);
        VBox buttons= new VBox(moveCircle,addCircle,reset,exit);
        buttons.setPadding(new Insets(SPACING,SPACING,SPACING,SPACING));
        buttons.setSpacing(SPACING);
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        primarystage.setTitle("LAB4");
        primarystage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 300));
        primarystage.show();

        Stage stage2= new Stage();
        stage2.setTitle("stage2");
        stage2.setX(primarystage.getX() + primarystage.getScene().getWidth()); // CHANGE HERE
        stage2.setY(primarystage.getY());
        stage2.setScene(new Scene(buttons));
        stage2.show();
        stage2.setMinWidth(200);
    }
}
```

This is what I get when I run the above code...

[image: screen capture]